# Drupal: A way to vote for best image in a given gallery

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, gallery, voting

We have a Drupal 7 site where we need users to choose the best image in an image gallery. I am going in circles trying to find the best way to accomplish this. I know there are "ratings" modules like 5 star etc, but we're not really wanting to rate each individual image on their own, but choose the BEST one and only one from the given gallery. This is more of a "poll" so I looked at Advanced Poll, but it no longer allows HTML as a poll choice so I can't attach an image as a poll choice. There is the Voting API also, but I'm not sure how to go about using it for what I need. Can anyone think of an easy way to create a gallery of images that when you go to the gallery, you can select which image is the best? I also need it to where only certain logged in users can vote.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can use vote up/down kind of module to achieve this.
List of images in each row with voting up/down button against each one.

User can vote up the images which he likes & you can sort desc order by votings & display the images.

Checkout these modules: 
https://drupal.org/project/rate 
https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down